# Asp.Net method that work for automatic file Upload

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

I am using FIleUpload on an asp.net C# page and a button which upload the browsed picture. if the file being uploaded qualify some validation it is saved and instantly shown in asp.net image below the upload button. I made alot of search to find out about asp.net FileUpload control autopostback method but could not find. The problem i am having is when the user click upload button and when the page is rendered back all values in textboxes disappear and page go to the top. I want to do this task using ajax but cannot do it as FileUpload has no autopostback event. Can anybody give me some idea or any alternative way of doing this. Also any method by usisng which user will not require upload button. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must do a full **PostBack** with the **FileUpload Control**, since it was not designed for asynchronous postback.

Look under *Using the FileUpload Control in Partial-Page Updates* in 
[MSDN FileUpload Web Server Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227677.aspx)

But you could try using an iframe and `<input type="file"/>` like in this example:
[Create an Ajax style File Upload](http://geekswithblogs.net/rashid/archive/2007/08/01/Create-An-Ajax-Style-File-Upload.aspx)

There is also an **AjaxFileUpload** Control from the **ASP.Net Control Toolkit**: http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/ajaxFileUpload/ajaxFileUpload.aspx

Comment: The example you provided (Create an Ajax style file upload) is good enough. I think i can work for me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I used swfupload. Works like gmail attach. Starts uploading upon selection and can return a thumb for you to display.

Comment: The poster may or may not be able to use Flash though.

Comment: I need something to do by myself rather than using tools as it is an academic project which strictly demand to do every task by code